# <x:out select="" /> does not accept a variable

Tags: xml, jsp

Thanks for your time.  I am working on my homework for class and have gotten myself stuck.  I'm not very familiar with JSP and this is my first week working with it so I'm not sure how to fix this problem.  How do I get x:out select="" to accept a variable? For instance what I want is:

```
<x:out select="$output/stores/store[${x}]/name" /> <br>
```

The error is "attribute select does not accept any expressions".  My question is how can I work around this?  My goal is to create a loop that cycles through all of the XML I'm loading.

Also does anyone know how to get the number of elements in an xml file?  I noticed in the XML I'm loading there are variables called to="6" total total="6" I just don't know how to access them.

Below is my full code if you need it.

Thanks,
Tommy

```
<%-- 
    Document   : newjsp
    Created on : Nov 30, 2013, 8:41:46 AM
    Author     : c8k
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.parsers.*"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <c:import var="stores" url="http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/stores(area(${param.zip},${param.dist}))?show=storeId,name,distance,lat,lng&apiKey=fuzgmrj4nv8v9ummatn78m3k"/>
        <x:parse xml="${stores}" var="output"/>
        <b>The first stores information is:</b> <br>

        <%! 
            boolean b = true;
            int x = 1;

        %>


            <x:out select="$output/stores/store[${x}]/storeId" /> <br>
            <x:out select="$output/stores/store[1]/name" /> <br>
            <x:out select="$output/stores/store[1]/distance" /> <br>
            <x:out select="$output/stores/store[1]/lat" /> <br>
            <x:out select="$output/stores/store[1]/lng" /> <br>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey everyone, I found another recourse that showed me a better way to do this.  So I have it up and running now.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how you achieved this ? Thanks

Comment: Hey, it's been a couple years but I think this was my final solution.
http://www.cloud-cadet.com/Code/JSP/JSPXmlUpload.php

Answer (score -1):

change <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %> is not right for me. for my project(web-app version="3.0" ) IDE(MyEclipse) I see the configuration file of x.tld.There is the false of select which do not allow the select apperance ${} or <%=%>.So I got a way to cheat in the web.xml.

1.`<jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/huang</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/x.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>`

add to web.xml

2.declare the new taglib-url name "huang" to my jsp file like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="/huang" %>
```

3.to use`<x:out select="$casexml//案例//${node.name }" />`

I can get the right result