# Error attribute select does not support any expression in <x:out select>

Tags: xml, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

```
<x:out select="$node/${pram.foo}" />
```

shows error **According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute select does not accept any expressions**

where `foo` is parameter passed in url like  `http://localhost/foo=bar`

How to resolve it?

**UPDATE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <%@include file="WEB-INF/jspf/common.jspf" %>
    <c:import url="WEB-INF/data/Plan.xml" var="planDoc" charEncoding="utf-8"/>
    <x:parse  xml="${planDoc}" var="plans"/>
```

**common.jspf**

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
```

Comment: I guess it is a problem with your xmlns declaration. Please update the question with the complete code of the JSP.

Comment: @unwichtich I have updated the code, please check it

Comment: I can't spot a problem in your code. Which web-app version do you have in your `web.xml`?

Comment: @unwichtich It is version 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you really can't use EL expressions (like `${param.foo}`) in the **select** element of `x:out`. Instead you can use a normal variable like this:

```
    <c:set var="foo" value="${param.foo}" />
    <x:out select="$node/$foo" />
```

**See also:**

- [does not accept a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302679/xout-select-does-not-accept-a-variable)
- [Error using JSTL XML taglib - attribute xml does not accept any expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377513/error-using-jstl-xml-taglib-attribute-xml-does-not-accept-any-expressions)